# Is it with GNU parallel possible to split on character count, but provide full lines only?

Tags: split, parallelism, gnu-parallel

I would like to split an input file on character count (ASCII is fine), combined with new lines as well. That is, every group of 10000 character should be seen as one record to be piped into the child process, but if that 10000th character does not happen to be at the end of line, the whole line should be included (and thus more that 10000 characters are provided). Each line should be considered as a single entity, which cannot be split.

Is that possible with GNU parallel (or possibly with a chain of other tools which might be useful)?

Comment: In that case you could use `split` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html with `-b` flag

Comment: Interesting... how can that be combined with `parallel` to keep processing the chunks in parallel? Should I introduce an artificial boundary character to allow `parallel` to split on?

Comment: With regards to `split`, I also think it should be `split -C 10k`, and not `-b`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is pretty much:

```
seq 100000 | parallel --block 10k --pipe wc
```

It will pass a block around 10000 bytes to `wc` but will only give full lines.

It will not guarantee that the block will be at least 10 kbytes, but it will at most be one line off.

Comment: Great! The guarantees are fine for my case.